# How do you print the complete bit without the prefixed zeroes being ignored?

Tags: python, dataframe, matrix, bit-manipulation, minimum

I have a DF which has values like:

```
       col1      col2        col3
row1   0010010   0011010     0010011
row2   0000011   0100011     1111111
row3   0101010   1101101     1100101
```

I am trying to fetch the minimum value of each column but, when I do a:

```
df.min (axis = 0,skipna = True)
```

I get the minimum values of each column however the initial zeroes are ignored and I get the rest of the values. For example, if the minimum value is `0010010` from `row1 col1`, I get `10010.0` in float.

How do I print all the bits without the zeroes prefixed being ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you 2 methods to achieve this.

**1.** If you are sure that the numbers will always be of 7 digits, convert all the values into string inside the dataframe.

You can convert it during reading csv into dataframe:

```
df = read_csv('myfile.csv', converters={'columnName': lambda x: str(x)})
```

You can convert it after you have data in your df.

```
df['columnName'] = df['columnName'].astype('str')
```

**2.** If you just want to print the values with proper formatting with leading zeroes, you can specify formatter while printing like below :

```
val = 10010.0
print("%07.0f" % val)

--> output = 0010010
```

Comment: Also upvote the answer it helps in gaining reputation and motivation :p